# How to convert RFC 2822 formated Date to EST Date

Tags: java, twilio

I'm getting date time as "Wed, 22 Jul 2015 18:19:23 +0000" from twilio API. As described in doc its a RFC 2822 format but don't describe time zone. Now i want to display this date to users in EST format. How to achieve this?

This is my sample code

```
Date sentDateInEST = new Date(twilioMessage.getDateSentInString());
System.out.println("Server date ="+twilioMessage.getDateSentInString());
//Getting Tue, 08 Sep 2015 09:11:52 +0000

DateFormat estFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));


System.out.println("sentDateInEST = "+estFormat.parse(estFormat.format(sentDateInEST)));
//Getting Tue Sep 08 04:11:52 EST 2015
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458524/parsing-rfc-2822-date-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
```

(you missed the Z at the end)

Comment: What it is indicating +0000?

Comment: I think this is GMT; GMT+1 would be +0100